# How to auto scroll table view when dragging cell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, cell

How can I auto scroll my table view up or down while dragging a cell, once I approach the last visible cell? I've tried many things, but nothing has worked smoothly for me, yet.

I have the method `handleLongPressChanged` being called when my long press gesture `gestureRecognizer.state` is `.changed`. I assume that this is where I need to add the dragging functionality. I've tried working with the `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` method, but I haven't been able to get it to work properly.

How would you do this?

[image]

Here's my extension that deals with user long pressing, which allows users to drag cells around:

```
import UIKit

private struct LongPressPersistentValues {
  static var indexPath: IndexPath?
  static var cellSnapShot: UIView?
}

extension CustomTableVC: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

  // MARK: - Long Press Setup

  func setUpTableViewLongPressGesture() {
  let longPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress))
  longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.3
  longPressGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
  tableView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGestureRecognizer)
  }

  // MARK: - Long Press Gesture Delegate Methods

  @objc func handleLongPress(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
      let locationInView = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.tableView)
      let currentIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: locationInView)

      switch gestureRecognizer.state {
      case .began:
          handleLongPressBegan(currentIndexPath, locationInView)
      case .changed:
          handleLongPressChanged(currentIndexPath, locationInView)
      case .ended:
          handleLongPressEnded()
      default:
          break
      }
  }

  // MARK: - Long Press Gesture Other Methods

  func snapshopOfCell(inputView: UIView) -> UIView {
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(inputView.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
      inputView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
      let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
      let cellSnapshot: UIView = UIImageView(image: image)
      cellSnapshot.layer.masksToBounds = false
      cellSnapshot.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0
      cellSnapshot.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -5.0, height: 0.0)
      cellSnapshot.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
      cellSnapshot.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
      return cellSnapshot
  }

  func handleLongPressBegan(_ currentIndexPath: IndexPath?, _ locationInView: CGPoint) {
      let hapticGenerator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
      hapticGenerator.notificationOccurred(.success)
      if currentIndexPath != nil {
          LongPressPersistentValues.indexPath = currentIndexPath
          guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: currentIndexPath!) else { return }
          LongPressPersistentValues.cellSnapShot = snapshopOfCell(inputView: cell)
          var center = cell.center
          LongPressPersistentValues.cellSnapShot?.center = center
          LongPressPersistentValues.cellSnapShot?.alpha = 0.0
          tableView.addSubview(LongPressPersistentValues.cellSnapShot!)

          UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
              center.y = locationInView.y
              LongPressPersistentValues.cellSnapShot?.center = center
              LongPressPersistentValues.cellSnapShot?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.05, y: 1.05)
              LongPressPersistentValues.cellSnapShot?.alpha = 0.98
              cell.alpha = 0.0
          }, completion: { _ in
              cell.isHidden = true
          })
      }
  }

  func handleLongPressChanged(_ currentIndexPath: IndexPath?, _ locationInView: CGPoint) {
      var center = LongPressPersistentValues.cellSnapShot?.center
      center?.y = locationInView.y
      LongPressPersistentValues.cellSnapShot?.center = center!
      if (currentIndexPath != nil) && (currentIndexPath != LongPressPersistentValues.indexPath) {
          delegate.moveElement(from: LongPressPersistentValues.indexPath!, to: currentIndexPath!)
          tableView.moveRow(at: LongPressPersistentValues.indexPath!, to: currentIndexPath!)
          LongPressPersistentValues.indexPath = currentIndexPath
      }
  }

  func handleLongPressEnded() {
      let hapticGenerator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
      hapticGenerator.impactOccurred()
      guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: LongPressPersistentValues.indexPath!) else { return }
      cell.isHidden = false
      cell.alpha = 0.0
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
          LongPressPersistentValues.cellSnapShot?.center = cell.center
          LongPressPersistentValues.cellSnapShot?.transform = .identity
          LongPressPersistentValues.cellSnapShot?.alpha = 0.0
          cell.alpha = 1.0
      }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
          if finished {
              LongPressPersistentValues.indexPath = nil
              LongPressPersistentValues.cellSnapShot?.removeFromSuperview()
          LongPressPersistentValues.cellSnapShot = nil
          self.tableView.reloadData()
          }
      })
  }

}
```

Comment: Autoscrolling is not difficult. But why not adopt drag-and-drop and let all the work be done for you?

Comment: I didn't adopt it because I had never heard of it, hahaha. Thank you for this! I will be taking a look over Apple's example project they posted at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drag_and_drop/adopting_drag_and_drop_in_a_table_view

Comment: Haha. Well, it's very easy, you just give the table view a `dragDelegate` and a `dropDelegate`, implement a couple of methods, and start dragging.

Comment: I read some of the drag-and-drop Apple documentation and tried to implement it in my code. My understanding of it is that this functionality is more for dragging an actual object between parts of your app, or even other apps (like in split-screen in an iPad). I wan't able to figure out how to have that help me scroll down my table view while dragging a cell. Am I misunderstanding the drag-and-drop functionality? I'm just looking for the table view to scroll down or up when dragging a cell, not dragging the object represented in the cell to a different place.

Comment: "I wan't able to figure out how to have that help me scroll down my table view while dragging a cell. Am I misunderstanding the drag-and-drop functionality?" Yes, I think you are. There are two built-in ways to allow the user to drag a cell up or down. One is the new drag-and-drop. The other is the old data source `tableView(_:canMoveRowAt:)`. They both work great, including autoscroll. And you are not using either of them. So it seems to me that, since you have devised some nonstandard hacky approach off your own bat, you have only yourself to blame if you have trouble with the hack.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, I do appreciate it. This is one of the first apps that I'm making, so there's a lot that I don't know how to implement yet, but I'm trying to figure it out. I didn't show it in the code above, but I do have the following code in a different file for the `CustomTableVC` class:

```override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }```

What else do you think I am missing to have this built-in way to drag a cell up or down, work?

Comment: You're not showing enough code for me to know why it _wouldn't_ work. Based on what you _have_ shown, the first step would be to get rid of all that long press gesture recognizer stuff and _use_ the built-in way instead.

Comment: Can you share thoughts about auto-scrolling the table view if we drag a cell at the end of the table view?